# mvc4 receive form in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a form in html and i want to submit it to a controler

#### what i have tried

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterApartmentOwner", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                            {
    <p>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first Name" name="firstName" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your last Name" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your password" name="Password"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Password Again</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your password again" name="Password2"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register"  class="submit"/>
    </p>
    }
</div>
```

and in the controller i receive the submit in this function

```
public String RegisterTenant() {
            return "done";
        }
```

i can see the `done` message, however, i want to receive the values of the input that i used in the form, how please?

i just to know what to receive the form in the controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could accept the [formcollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) (as in: `FormCollection collection`) as a parameter in your post action, or, better yet, create a view model, send that to the view and post it to the controller. You'd have to set it as a parameter of your http post action course.

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public String RegisterTenant(FormCollection collection) {
        // give all your html elements you want to read values out of an Id, like 'Password'
        var password = collection["Password"];
        // do something with your data
        return "done";
    }
```

Or (better!):

View model:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}
```

View (on top):

```
@model Namespace.HomeViewModel
```

View (in your form):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public String RegisterTenant(HomeViewModel model)
{
    var userName = model.UserName;
    // do something
}
```

But you should really do some investigation into MVC: Views, Models & Controllers and what they do. It is really better to create a typesafe view model and work with that.